# Make the android app as the only sms receiving (inbox and notification) app for a specific sender/originating address

Tags: android, sms, android-broadcastreceiver, smsmanager

My aim is to show notification and the sms message in inbox of app only from a specific broadcast sender. But using broadcast reciever with Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED receives the sms in the app as well as the main android phone's inbox. So the result is redundant message notifications and backups in phone default inbox as well as app inbox.
Following link shows how to create default sms app for android 4.4 and above for all the senders. 
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html
Also, for older versions, abortBroadcast() was used for receiving the sms into a specific app only.
**But I want to make an application that notifies and saves the messages only from a particular sender as it is only application specific. Also the message must not go to any other sms inbox apart from app**
Is there anyway to do the same ? Or can data sms with specific port number help ?

Usecase: The message to be notified by the app is a user specific message or a broadcast sms. The app has to notify the user of the message even when app is not open,

Comment: What if your side chick changes her number?

Comment: The situation is : I am the sender and friends/clients using my app are the receivers. So I am in control of the number and the app

Comment: Is it necessary to use SMS then? I mean if they manually need to go into the app to see anything wouldn't it be easier to push to the app directly via web? Edit: you also want to set a notification that is app specific when they get the SMS? Basically this seems like you are using SMS instead  of the internet but with people that use smartphones - is that the case? What's the purpose of the app that can not be achieved with regular SMS?

Comment: Just that the app must notify the user and save these notifications in the app's inbox so that the users can have the datewise log of the notifications.

Comment: So a single application showing the SMS notification is not possible unless it is the default app that notifies and reads all the sms from all the senders. So basically implement a fully functional sms app and make it default. Is it ?

Comment: @MikeM. Was aking about the normal SMS (not data) message that is received by SMS_RECEIVED or SMS_DELIVER